# How would I model a .proto file that results in the following C# Class?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, proto

```
syntax = "proto3"

message ResponseDto {
   map<string, FirstDictionary> FD = 1;
}

message FirstDictionary {
   map<string, SecondDictionary> SD = 1;
}
...etc
```

Note: Example output after running protoc

The problem is that I cant seem to generate a suitable class without having to explicitly include a property for the nested dictionaries

```
public class ResponseDto : Dictionary<string, FirstDictionary>
{

}

public class FirstDictionary : Dictionary<string, SecondDictionary>
{

}

public class SecondDictionary
{
    public bool SomeFlag { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, SomeClass> SomeProp { get; set; } 
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public bool SomeOtherFlag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So you don't want the equivalent of the FD/SD properties? Yeah, that's not going to work, honestly. What have you go against them? Why does it matter? Usually, a serialization model is geared to the serializer, and then you remap that to your domain model, so: any nuances required by the serializer don't impact your domain model in any way, as it is separate.

Comment: :D Thanks for the super swift reply Marc, yeah having thought about it - youre actually right tbf. The example class is an existing one originally modelled that way to try to reduce the payload size where possible when serializing to JSON, and serialising via protobuf essentially means the properties are pretty redundant during transmission anyway right?